# How to fix invalid syntax for hostname error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a homework where I am suppose to set up a TCP server + client. I've got an example from the book (Computer Networking A Top-Down Approach) and all I have to do is type in the serverName (the IP address for my computer).

The problem is with the client, when I'm typing in the private IP address ('''.'''.0.''') and start the program, I get an error [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMhMl.png) saying invalid syntax, and then it marks the 0 red [The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS4EV.png). And same error if I try to type in the public IP, it marks the same spot red.

Example code
TCPClient.py

```
from socket import *
serverName = 'serverName'
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))
sentence = input('Input lowercase sentence: ')
clientSocket.send(sentence.encode())
modifiedSentence = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print ('From Server:', modifiedSentence.decode())
clientSocket.close()
```

Expected outcome is to connect to server and then type in a sentence. The server will then send back same sentence but uppercase instead of lowercase.

Comment: You said "the ip adress of my computer", right? Have you tried the ip 'localhost'? (or '127.0.0.1')

Comment: It's marking the same spot every time, no matter what.

Comment: I don't understand: what is marking the spot? How are you running this script exactly?

Comment: Not sure that I get the question, but the program I use is the one that I got on python.org and that program marked the 0 red and said invalid syntax. When I tried to run the program

Comment: Ok, so you are running your script in a console, right? And you get an error while running your client script? or is this when you run the server script? Could you post the exact error message?

Comment: Also, please consider reading this, people will be more likely to help you if you provide the good informations at first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are `serverName` and `serverPort` correct values? when I call `cientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))` I get `socket.gaierror`...We need your error messages ...

Comment: **Do not** post screenshots of text in a question... please copy & paste the *text* of the code & error you get.

Comment: I can't be sure this is correct, since you redacted the actual problem, but I can reproduce that error if I neglect to put quotes around the IP address. i.e. `serverName = 1.2.3.4` instead of the correct `serverName = '1.2.3.4'`. As Giacomo said, please don't post images of code or errors. Copy and paste the actual text (and format appropriately in the post). If you need to redact, just change the numbers/text before posting.